# Error Running a Batch File To Copy A File

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to run a batch file to copy a backup file from one location to other.

I keep on getting the error:

```
Invalid drive specification
```

My path is as follows:

```
\\server\drive:\folder\folder\folder\*.bak  drive:\folder\.bak
```

Comment: Could you post the code?

Comment: How are you trying to do this? The tag is "sql-server", are you using xp_cmdshell?

You say the path starts with \server. Do you mean \server ?

Comment: @Kevin: My guess is that the OP is using a batch file to copy a SQL Server backup (hence the `bak` extension). The syntax is that of the `cp` command in Windows Batch.

Comment: @Eric hehe ok, makes sense.
Oh, and I didn't know double backslashes get replaced by a single backslash :( my comment looks kinda dumb... oh well!

Comment: @Kevin: Use the backticks, \`, in your comment to get the code, or double up your backslashes, `\\like\this` or \\\\like\\this.

Answer (score 2):

That typically doesn't work out too well. You'll want this:

```
cp \\server\C$\folder\folder\folder\copy.bak C:\folder\copied.bak
```

This presupposes that you actually have access to the folder `\\server\C$\folder\folder\folder` from your box. If you do not, then you need to configure permissions correctly on the server to give you access.

Answer (score 2):

You only have access to administrative shares (`\\server\C$` <- the $ denotes an admin share) if you have administrative rights on the server. If you don't you need to actively share the folder in question, i.e. on the server, navigate to `drive:\folder\folder\folder` and share it (context menu of the folder, menu item *Sharing and Security*). Note that you need at least temporary admin rights on the server in order to create a share.

Do not forget to configure the permissions for the share you create, so that the limited account you are using for the copy process has read rights.

Once this is et up, you should be able to copy the files using

```
Copy \\Server\NewShareName\*.bak  c:\folder\.bak
```

If you have problems with the files being in use by another process, have a look at [robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy) instead of the copy command.